# How does attrition work

Tags: civilization-5, civilization-5-gods-and-kings

I recently made a helicopter gunship and it said I could position it over mountains. 
So, I moved it onto one of my mountains. A few turns later, my gunship dies of attrition.

**How does this happen - How does attrition work?**

I was not at war with anyone at this time, and it would have alerted me if there was a barbarian (i'm not even sure if there are barbarians anymore).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Helicopter Gunships receive damage if kept on a mountain tile. They state this in their informational view.

Comment: I was not aware of this.

Comment: This applies to *any* unit that ends it's turn (or remains stationary) on mountain terrain. I think it's 50% for all units, but check the tooltip in case it varies.